# How to open default ftp server path when we click fileupload control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am trying to open a ftp server when I click on browse button on File upload control in asp.net.
I tried checking for default propertied but no luck.

Example: When  I click on browser, it should display files which are there in a particular path in a server "//servername/abc/files"

Note: The server folder is shared with everyone.

Is there a way to get this thing done.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried few possibilities, but no luck. Is it possible to fetch files from server and display it below the browse button and the link of the server should appear in the text box next to browse button?

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this using text box and button, when I click on button, I made a pop-up window and display the files in the server.
Thus this pop-up window acts like a file browser.